# Unable to insert timestamp values while using model's custom method

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am doing project in Laravel. I have used laravel's eloquent model. I want to insert record into the database with timestamp values.

Here is my model **'Provider.php'**

```
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'provider_id';
    protected $table = 'provider';

    protected $fillable = [
        'organization_name',
        'email',
        'website',
        'mobile',
        'landline',
        'password',
        'added_by'
    ];

    public function cities(){

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\City','provider_city','provider_id','city_id');
    }
}
```

**'City.php'**

```
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'city_id';
    protected $table = 'city';

    protected $fillable = ['state_id','name'];
}
```

and my controller method is as following,

```
{
    $city_selection = $request->input('city_selection');
    $provider = Provider::findOrFail($provider_id);
    foreach ($city_selection as $city) {
        $provider->cities()->attach($city['city_id']);
    }

}
```

where city_selection is as below,

```
"city_selection":
    [
      {
         "city_id": 1,
         "name": "Pune"
      },
      {
        "city_id": 3,
        "name": "Bangalore"
      }
    ]
```

After that when I tried to insert the record then all fileds i.e. provider_id and city_id filed goes properly into the database but the only problem is created_at and updated_at fields are still null.

I have used timpstamps(); while creating migration file. I don't know what's going wrong.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sometimes it is due to memory cache. Try to clear it hope it will be fixed. Also check this discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68278605/unable-to-enable-timestamps-again/68297360#68297360

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the dates mutators.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators

```
class Provider extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'deleted_at'
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add timestamp in your Schema

```
$table->timestamps();
```

Your schema look like this

```
Schema::create('city', function(Blueprint $table){
  $table->increments('id');
  $table->integer('state_id')->unsigned();
  $table->foreign('state_id')->references('id')->on('state');     
  $table->string('name', 100);        
  $table->timestamps();
});
```

Comment: Yes I have added that

Answer (score 0):

Add following columns in your table schema.

```
$table->timestamp('created_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
$table->timestamp('updated_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
```

`created_at` column will store value when record is inserted and `updated_at` will keep updated when any changes in this record(Any update in row).

**Update**

Use below code to update in new migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('table_name', function($table) {
        $table->timestamp('created_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
        $table->timestamp('updated_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
    });
}
```

Comment: To change the type of timestamp,created migration file, but while migrating this file I got error as,        [Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]
  Unknown column type "timestamp" requested. Any Doctrine type that you use has to be registered with \Doctrine\DBAL
  \Types\Type::addType(). You can get a list of all the known types with \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::getTypesMap(). I
  f this error occurs during database introspection then you might have forgot to register all database types for a
  Doctrine Type. Use AbstractPlatform...

Comment: This error will come when you try to alter/update any table.

Comment: As error says you can install `Doctrine` if you want to update any table or just rollback your migration and add this column and run migrate again.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, but I have already installed Doctrine. and as I have created this table before long time ago I dont think its good to rollback lots of tables just to change the type of one table....Do you have any other solution plz