# Unable to enable timestamps again

Tags: php, laravel

I have used this code to disable updated_at timestamp

```
public $timestamps = ['created_at'];
const UPDATED_AT = null;
```

Now I want to bring it back, I have removed above code, added column, but it's null. Tried to drop migration, migrated with `$table->timestamps()`, it's still null (on creation and doesn't listen to `protected $touches`). I have tried `public $timestamps = true;`, but still null.

My model is that simple:

```
class Visitor extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function visits()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Visit::class);
    }
}
```

Any idea what happened and why I am unable to bring timestamp back?

p.s. I tried clearing cache too

Comment: Just bare in mind pivot tables MUST have timestamps if you're using Eloquent.

Comment: @KaleemShoukat they have, but updated_at is always null, I tried `$item->touch()` too, but it's still null

Comment: Add: public $timestamps = true; and also add created_at in $fillable then try again.

Comment: Hope it will work if not then try below solution.

Comment: @KaleemShoukat The problem was in memory cache ... I terminated queued job and started it again and it got fixed, I spent several hours for fixing correct code ... Sorry for bothering and thanks a lot for trying to help me.

Comment: No problem, I also learned from your question. SO is here for such services!

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a migration like this for required table.

```
$table->timestamp('created_at')->default(\DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
$table->timestamp('updated_at')->default(\DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
```